# Pressing tab key closes Material UI Dialog that is opened from a submenu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to create a menubar with a number of menus that have submenus. When I open a dialog from a top level menu item, everything works as desired/expected. BUT when I open a dialog from a submenu, pressing the tab key closes the dialog.

I've tried several different ways of implementing the nested menus and settled on the approach discussed here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11723

I've created sample code to demonstrate the problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-heisenberg-rvwwb
You'll see this is forked from the submenu example I found on GitHub. There were a few things I changed because I wasn't sure how to add the opening of a dialog from that example, so I'm not sure the way I did it is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that <kbd>Tab</kbd> is triggering close of the parent Menu which then causes the Dialog to be unmounted. You could use state to prevent the parent Menu from closing whenever the Dialog is open, but that leaves a different problem. Regardless of whether the parent Menu closes, when a <kbd>Tab</kbd> occurs it calls `event.preventDefault()` which then prevents the <kbd>Tab</kbd> from changing the focus location (the default browser behavior).

You can fix this by having the `Dialog` stop propagation of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key event. This prevents `Menu` from receiving it, so `Menu` won't try to close itself and it won't call `event.preventDefault()`. I can't guarantee that this won't introduce some new issues, but this fixes the issue described.

```
const stopPropagationForTab = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Tab") {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

      <Dialog
        onKeyDown={stopPropagationForTab}
```

[image: Edit Cascading Menus with Dialog]

In my fork of your sandbox, I upgraded the Material-UI version from 1.2 to 4.0 just because I wanted to make sure the issues weren't related to aspects that have changed. This threw off some of the styling, but the main behavior being addressed seemed to work the same in both versions.

---

A different way to handle this problem would be to rework the code such that the Dialog is no longer a child of the Menu. Then clicking a menu item that opens a Dialog would set state at the top-level for closing all the menus and opening the Dialog. This would probably be a better way to handle this, but it is a bigger change to the code structure.

Comment: thank you for explaining this behavior and the suggested fixes. I will be reworking the code as suggested...

Comment: Fo someone that uses a `Modal` instead `Dialog`, you can apply the same solution, adding the event to `onKeyDown` in the first child of the `Modal` (in my case it was a `Box`).